# Python set-item in nested dict with path

Tags: python

Suppose there is a nested dict with various kinds of info (as below). I always have a way of storing the path of the immediately relevant item, but not a good way of storing data to the original dict (because dicts unlike arrays won't simply point to the memory space of the object).

```
sample_dict = 
{ 'title': <book_title>,
  'author': {'first_name': <first_name>, 'last_name': <last_name>, 'date_of_birth':<date of birth>},
 'publisher': {'publisher_name': <publisher_name>, 'contact_info': {'address': <address>, 'email': <email>}}
} (or etc)
```

That is to say with a path like so (to retrieve a publishers email):

```
publisher_email_path = 'publisher.contact_info.email' 
temp_dict=sample_dict
for node in publisher_email_path.split('.'): 
  temp_dict = temp_dict.get(node)
```

But the opposite for storing a new (for example publisher email) will not work, since:

```
for node in publisher_email_path.split('.')[:-1]: 
    temp_dict = temp_dict.get(node)
temp_dict['email'] = <new_email>
```

will only update a temp_dict, but not the original. One option seems to be recursively updating each sub-dict starting from the smallest and going to the top-most - but this seems quite ugly. 
Ideally one would be able to do sample_dict[node[node[node]]] for each node in the path - but I'm not sure if there is a work around to replicate '[' ']'  brackets.

Comment: The `temp_dict` *is* in the original somewhere (*if* it is found). One issue is that the code is not *moving* up the tree. So every call to `temp_dict = sample_dict.get(node)` returns the node *in* the original dictionary (if it exists), not a nested directory of a nested directory therein. (Also that should result in a None error if using a path that doesn't end in a top-level dictionary.)

Comment: Please create a **complete** short program that demonstrates the problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve or http://SSCCE.org for more information.

Comment: "*Ideally one would be able to do `sample_dict[node[node[node]]]`*" - The syntax for that is `sample_dict['publisher']['contact_info']['email']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had several syntax errors and one logic error in your program.

The logic error was your use of `sample_dict`. You had

```
for ...:
   temp_dict = sample_dict.get(...)
```

It should have been

```
temp_dict = sample_dict
for ...:
   temp_dict = temp_dict.get(...)
```

Here is the fixed version of your sample. Notice the use of `temp_dict` in the `for` loops.

```
sample_dict = {
    'title': '<book_title>',
  'author': {'first_name': '<first_name>', 'last_name': '<last_name>', 'date_of_birth':'<date of birth>'},
 'publisher': {'publisher_name': '<publisher_name>', 'contact_info': {'address': '<address>', 'email': '<email>'}}
}

publisher_email_path = 'publisher.contact_info.email'
temp_dict=sample_dict
for node in publisher_email_path.split('.'):
  temp_dict = temp_dict.get(node)
print temp_dict  # prints '<email>'


temp_dict = sample_dict
for node in publisher_email_path.split('.')[:-1]:
    temp_dict = temp_dict.get(node)
temp_dict['email'] = '<new_email> '

publisher_email_path = 'publisher.contact_info.email'
temp_dict=sample_dict
for node in publisher_email_path.split('.'):
  temp_dict = temp_dict.get(node)
print temp_dict  # prints '<new_email>'
```

By the way, you can also express your `for` loop using the `reduce` function:

```
publisher_email_path = 'publisher.contact_info.email'.split('.')
print reduce(dict.get, publisher_email_path, sample_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Uhhm ... what you're claiming *doesn't* work, actually *does*, at least in python 2.7:

```
>>> d = {1:{2:''}}
>>> d2 = d[1]
>>> d
{1: {2: ''}}
>>> d2
{2: ''}
>>> d2[3]=4
>>> d
{1: {2: '', 3: 4}}
>>> d2
{2: '', 3: 4}
```